# What are the advantages of using Depends in FastAPI over just calling a dependent function/class?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi

FastAPI provides a [way](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) to manage dependencies, like DB connection, via its own dependency resolution mechanism.

It resembles a `pytest` fixture system.
In a nutshell, you declare what you need in a function signature, and FastAPI will call the functions(or classes) you mentioned and inject the correct results when the handler is called.

Yes, it does caching(during the single handler run), but can't we achieve the same thing using just `@lru_cache` decorator and simply calling those dependencies on each run? 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Self plug: I created a side project to support dependency injection of multiple scopes within an app (full application lifetime, vs shorter request scopes). A primary goal was to also enable writing non-webapp code (e.g. cli-tooling) which could reuse the DI system without needing be tied to frameworks like FastAPI/Flask/etc. My library `flexdi` has integration with the FastAPI depends system and a few others to provide these multiple scopes. https://flexdi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fastapi.html I use this in a few smaller projects I own, and so far it works quite nicely.

Answer (score 34):

FastAPI will also inject parameters from the request into your dependencies, and include them into the OpenApi specification.

This allows you to re-use parameters, which can help you write less code, especially if your project grows large.

Without the dependency injection you'd have to specify the parameters on every route, every time.

In this example from the [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#declare-the-dependency-in-the-dependant) we have common search parameters being shared.

```py
async def common_parameters(q: str = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return {"q": q, "skip": skip, "limit": limit}

@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(commons: dict = Depends(common_parameters)):
    return commons

@app.get("/users/")
async def read_users(commons: dict = Depends(common_parameters)):
    return commons
```

Comment: Agreed. But, using `pytest` notation again, those are of different "scope" - i.e., live as long as request is processing.

What if I need a persistent object for an app lifetime, which is built via several composition levels?

Comment: Yeah, these are executed on every request. You'd have to implement that logic inside the function yourself.